# Apache regular expression on RewriteRule, "or" syntax

Tags: regex, apache

I'm tiring to get all string before first slash when an url ends with "word1" or "word2", and im using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/word1|word2/?$            index.php?query=$1 [NC]
```

I haven't any problem with url that have "word1" on his ends, but if the url ends with "word2", Apache dose not return any value to "query" variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group the alternations in your expression:

```
^(.+)/(?:word1|word2)/?$
```

Without the grouping your expression means:

`^(.+)/word1` **or** `word2/?$`

Comment: `(?:regex)` is a non-capturing group, the same as `(regex)` except that it doesn't capture anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(word1|word2)/?$
```